# Loading a readme from github?

Tags: javascript, ajax, github

I have the following code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lemony-Andrew/SFML-Game-Engine/master/README",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

It simply retrieves a readme page from github, but is denied access. How can I "merge" or load a basic readme(or description) from github? Like seen in Careers 2.0, It shows the date the project was created and a snippet of the description.

Is it possible?

If you'd like to see it, the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lemony-Andrew/SFML-Game-Engine/master/README.
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'https://render.githubusercontent.com' that is not equal to the
>   supplied origin. Origin 'https://c9.io' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: You can't make cross-domain AJAX requests that the target server doesn't allow. Make a request to your server, which will make the request to get the README, then return that to your JS

Comment: I'm kind of new to all of this, well, relearning. So what are you saying? I send a ajax call to a php page on my own server that tries to fetch the page on github?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying! Since you don't own github.com and aren't making a request from within that domain, browsers won't let you. Servers can "allow" this cross-domain communication, but Github hasn't. So you'll have to let your server (PHP) make the request and return the result for you

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a very appropriate approach, but would you consider that over Martins answer?

Comment: Martin's answer basically is the same, except the request is to a different server (not your PHP), and accomplishes the same thing effectively. Although it does require support for CORS (which he includes browser support stats for). His second paragraph suggests that creating your own proxy (what I said) is the better solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make cross domain requests. However, modern browsers support CORS and some lovely guys have set up a heroku proxy to GitHub content... So in modern browsers the following will work:

```
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://github-raw-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/Lemony-Andrew/SFML-Game-Engine/master/README",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

A better solution would be to write a proxy yourself on the same domain and then call GitHub. This will work in older browsers and you wouldn't be taking any dependencies on other peoples services.

Here is the current browser support matrix for CORS: http://caniuse.com/#search=cors

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Another question is: Where did you come up with that adress? For future reference of course.

Comment: It's a node.js project over on GitHub: https://github.com/zeke/github-raw-cors-proxy